# SQL query to return rows where only one record is present in a given status

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with data similar to below.  I am trying to get a list of results that will display all rows where only one unique SourceID exists in status 10.  If I were querying this table, I would expect ID's 3 and 4 to be returned.

[Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1UyP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t1 WHERE t1.SourceID = t.SourceID AND t1.Status <> t.Status);
```

Comment: A variation of this ultimately achieved what I was looking for.  Thank you.

SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT SourceID FROM Supplemental_Diag_Extraction t1 WHERE t1.SourceID = t.SourceID AND t1.Status= 4)
and t.Status = 10

Answer (score 1):

```
Select *

From table

Where Status = 10 and Source ID in

(
Select SourceID

From Table

Group by SourceID

Having Count(*) = 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that would work?

```
SELECT ID FROM Mytable
WHERE [Status] = 10
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(SourceID) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub-query to check if t there is an exact count of 1 of those source id's

```
 SELECT t.* FROM YourTable t WHERE t.status = 10 
                            AND
                            (SELECT COUNT(0) x From YourTable t2
                                               where t2.sourceid = t.sourceid) = 1
```

Comment: Could you provide some narrative describing your solution so the original poster, and others that come looking, can understand your code?

Answer (score 0):

First, find out all the unique SourceIDs

```
SELECT 
    SourceID 
FROM 
    Data
GROUP BY
    SourceID
HAVING
    COUNT(SourceID) = 1
```

And then use this query as a sub query to get all the rows that has unique SourceID;

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Data 
WHERE
    SourceID IN (
        SELECT 
            SourceID 
        FROM 
            Data
        GROUP BY
            SourceID
        HAVING
            COUNT(SourceID) = 1
    )
```